# Inverse Transformation

Tags: functions, inverse

> > Consider the coordinate transformation
> >     $$
> > \varphi\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2, (x,y)\mapsto (y-\arctan(x),y+\arctan(x)).
> > $$
> >     To make it more easy, I set: 
> >     $$
> > \xi:=y-\arctan(x),~~~~~\eta:=y+\arctan(x).
> > $$
> >     When I am not wrong, then this is no $C^2$-diffeomorphism, because the inverse transformation, which is concerning to my calculation
> >     $$
> > x=\tan(-\frac{1}{2}((\xi-\eta)+n\pi), n\in\mathbb{N},~~~~~y=\eta-\arctan(\tan(-\frac{1}{2}((\xi-\eta)+n\pi)), n\in\mathbb{N}
> > $$
> >     is not bijective.

So my question is which is an adequate domain of definition in order to get a bijective inverse transformation?

Or do I have to restrict the domain of dfefinition of $\varphi$?

Comment: $\varphi$ is not surjective. Assuming the principal branch of $\arctan$ is taken for $\varphi$, the range is $\{(\xi,\eta) : \lvert \eta - \xi\rvert < \pi\}$.

Comment: Ok, so the inverse trafo has to be $\varphi^{-1}\colon\left\{(\xi,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\lvert \xi-\eta\rvert <\pi\right\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $(\xi,\eta)\longmapsto (\tan(-\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\eta)),\eta-\arctan(\tan(-\frac{1}{2}(\xi-\eta)))$?

Comment: I do not know what then is the domain of definition of the inverse transformation, because the set that you gave depends on (x,y), right?

Comment: No. Let $S = \{(\xi,\eta) : \lvert \eta-\xi\rvert < \pi\}$. $x$ and $y$ don't enter into the definition of $S$. Then $\varphi \colon\mathbb{R}^2\to S$ is a diffeomorphism, with inverse $\varphi^{-1}(\xi,\eta) = \left(\tan \left(\frac12(\eta-\xi)\right), \frac12(\eta+\xi)\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation $\varphi$ is injective, but not surjective. It is the composition of the diffeomorphism

$$\varphi_1 \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times\mathbb{R};\quad \varphi_1(x,y) = (\arctan x, y),$$

the injection $\iota \colon (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and the linear isomporphism

$$\varphi_2 \colon (u,v) \mapsto (v-u, v+u)$$

of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The image of $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times\mathbb{R}$ under $\varphi_2$ is the strip

$$S = \left\lbrace (\xi,\eta) : \lvert \eta-\xi\rvert < \pi\right\rbrace,$$

so $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$ is a diffeomorphism, with inverse

$$\varphi^{-1} = \varphi_1^{-1} \circ \varphi_2^{-1}\lvert_S \colon (\xi,\eta) \mapsto \left(\tan \frac{\eta-\xi}{2},\, \frac{\eta+\xi}{2} \right).$$